# Get percentage value of matching between templates and image using opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv

I have multiple image templates of some objects and my app should allow the user to input random images with random size and I want to use OpenCV to create a method that will take a template and the user image and return the percentage of the similarity or the matching in some cases

Example:

the user input is only a ball in the street

and the three templates is the ball, apple, and car images so the results should be 1 for the ball template because the image contains ball and zero with car template and between 0and 1 for the apple template because the apple has some similarity with ball

Any snippet code or hints are appreciated I can work on the code if it needs any improvements

I have this following code that will measure the matching but it not return the similarity on the matching percentage of the template in the image

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('big_image.jpg', 0)
template = cv2.imread('ball.jpg', 0)

h, w = template.shape

img2 = img.copy()
result = cv2.matchTemplate(img2, template, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
location = min_loc
bottom_right = (location[0] + w + 10, location[1] + h + 10)
cv2.rectangle(img2, location, bottom_right, 255, 2)
cv2.imshow('Match', img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I will add any more info if need it

Comment: Use TM_CCOEFF_NORMED. Then multiply the max_val by 100. Max_val should be in range 0 to 1 most of the time.

Comment: @fmw42 thank you for your quick response but sometime `max_val` gives negative values

Comment: That is correct, but rare. The full possible range is -1 to +1.  You could scale between those ranges or just clip negative values. Then multiply by 100.

Comment: @fmw42 do you mean .5 is equal to -.5

Comment: -1 goes to 0 and +1 goes to +1.  Divide by 2 and add 0.5. Then multiply by 100. But I don't think that would be good. I think the best would be to clip negative values and multiply by 100.  Alternately, use TM_SQDIFF. Divide by (255*255) to normalize to range 0 to 1, if doing it on 8-bit data. Then subtract from 1 (since perfect score is 0) and multiply by 100.